# How to make particles fall straight down instead of initially going up?

Tags: particles

Hey guys I was creating a particle system and I want the particles to directly fall down instead of the usual way where they go slightly up before they fall down.I even tried turning off all the force field settings except gravity but it didn't worked.So,if anybody has any idea please share.[image]

Comment: I tried decreasing the normal under emitter geometry in velocity to 0 and it solved to a great extend.Still the particles do go slightly up before they fall down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of the direction that the normals are facing. If you rotate your plane 180° on the Y or X axis (upside down), it will be resolved.

Also you can flip your normals by going into edit mode and select all faces. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to flip the normals.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Glad I could help, keep blending!